# I need to find two matrices $A,B$ in $M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ such that ...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, examples-counterexamples, c-star-algebras

Im doing an exercise on C*-algebras where I have two find a C*-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ and two positive (i.e. self-adoint(=hermitian) and spectrum contained in $[0,\infty)$) elements $a,b\in\mathscr{A}$ such that $ab$ is not positive.

Since one can prove that $ab$ is positive when $a$ and $b$ commute, my guess was to find two non-commuting positive matrices $A$, $B$ in the non-abelian C*-algebra $\mathscr{A}:=M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $AB$ is not positive.

Note that a matrix $A$ is positive iff $A=\overline{A}^{T}$ and the eigenvalues of $A$ lie in $[0,\infty)$.

Since $A=\overline{A}^{T}$ is always satisfied for symmetric matrices with real coefficients, I was hoping two find two such matrices. However, I did not succeed. In particular I tried $$A:=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix},$$ which has eigenvalues $0$ and $2$. But I can't find a $B$ that provides a counterexample together with this $A$.

Comment: Try a diagonal matrix with two different diagonal entries.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks! That was easier than I thought. It worked. I was focusing to much on the eigenvalues.

Comment: It is notable that for self-adjoint $A,B,$ $AB$ will be self-adjoint if and only if $A$ and $B$ commute.  Note that in the finite-dimensional case, self-adjoint matrices commute if and only if they are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Comment: Also worth noting: if $A$ and $B$ are positive definite matrices, $AB$ has the same eigenvalues as the positive definite matrix $A^{1/2} B A^{1/2}$, and in particular its eigenvalues are positive reals.